# Universal message broker

Tags: web-development-server

I think about universal message broker for collect project messages. 
I would like to have possibility to write messages (debug, warnings, notices, etc...) from anywhere, and then show all of them in one place with ability of filtering.

For example I have web page, where I can run some process and display status to user. The process is separate process of OS, so I am not able to write from there directly to browser. But I would like to see messages from this process (traces, asserts, etc...) as well as from server page script (PHP for example).

I hope there are any ready solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the ability to manage the server configuration, why not have the separate process generate log entries via syslog, then use a simple server-side script to examine the log entries thus generated, and present them in the browser in whatever fashion you find most useful? Syslog already is a "universal message broker", after all, and it's almost always easier to make use of an existing capability than to develop a new one from scratch.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to present a really specific answer, because you haven't identified the server-side language you're using; if you'll edit your question to include that information, and comment on my answer to let me know you've done so, I'll see what I can come up with to give you a real start on solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have thought about that exactly like you, but I hoped  that there is some solution for parsing syslog and representing it in browser, (or anywhere else).

I develop on PHP language, and after unsuccessful searching I decided to write such script for me. But instead os syslog I think about using MongoDB for collect debug messages.

Thanks again, and Best regards!

Comment: @Andrew Parsing syslog messages doesn't seem like it should be all that hard, depending on what you need to accomplish; in any case, though, it sounds like you've got something in mind that will work, even if it does seem like reinventing the wheel a bit. Good luck!